# WSO2 Multipart Binary Passthrough and MultipartFormData

Tags: wso2, multipartform-data, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

We are currently using WSO EI 6.4 as ESB.

We made the configuration to get the behaviour "Binary Passthrough" in axis2.xml for one carbon application

```xml
<messageBuilder     contentType="multipart/form-data"   class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
<messageFormatter   contentType="multipart/form-data"   class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

But now, we need to develop a new carbon application who need to create a multipart message.
and so we need to change the configuration to, as decribed in [this article](https://www.yenlo.com/blogs/multipart-form-data-uploads-wso2-ei-esb/)

```xml
<messageBuilder     contentType="multipart/form-data"   class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder" />
<messageFormatter   contentType="multipart/form-data"   class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
```

But if we do that, we will lose the "Binary Passthrough" adn broke the first carbon app.

Is there a possiblitiy to override the messageBuilder and messageFormatter just for one carbon application?

Thank you

---

### Solution

With the help of @tmoasz i was able to solve this issue.
Here the full solution

```xml
<inSequence>

      <!--Extract value from Json-->
      <property name="Data1" expression="json-eval($.Data1)"/>
      <property name="Data2" expression="json-eval($.Data2)"/>
      <property name="File1" expression="json-eval($.File1)"/>

      <!-- remove body and set MessageBuilder
        if body not removed, MultipartFormDataFormatter is not call
      -->
      <script language="js">
        mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().detach();
      </script>
      <builder>
        <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
          class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"
          formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
      </builder>

      <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <root xmlns="">
            <metadata xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data"
              filename="key1"
              name="key1">$1</metadata>
            <!-- content is decode from base64-->
            <file xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data"
              filename="file1.1"
              name="file1.1"
              content-type="application/xml">$3</file>
            <!-- content is not changed-->
            <metadata xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data"
              name="file1.2"
              filename="file1.2"
              content-type="application/xml">$3</metadata>
          </root>
        </format>
        <args>
          <arg expression="get-property('Data1')"/>
          <arg expression="get-property('Data2')"/>
          <arg expression="get-property('File1')"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>

            <!--set messageType to trigger multiPart Formater -->
            <property name="messageType"  scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            <!--remove ContentType to force generate header content-type with boundary information -->
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>

      <send>
        <endpoint>
          <http method="post" uri-template="http://127.0.0.1:3000/mulitPart/wso2">
            <suspendOnFailure>
              <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
              <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
              <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
              <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
          </http>
        </endpoint>
      </send>


    </inSequence>
```

Curl for test

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8280/outgoing-mail' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "Data1": "Value1",
    "Data2": "Value2",
    "File1" :  "PHhtbD4gICAKICAgIDxoZWxsbz5TdGFjazwvaGVsbG8+CjwveG1sPg=="
}'
```

Multipart Generated

```
--MIMEBoundary_dfa6d9a4ea9eee573969c1fae03dd6667159a66375689ec7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key1"; filename="key1"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Value1
--MIMEBoundary_dfa6d9a4ea9eee573969c1fae03dd6667159a66375689ec7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1.1"; filename="file1.1"
Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<xml>   
    <hello>Stack</hello>
</xml>
--MIMEBoundary_dfa6d9a4ea9eee573969c1fae03dd6667159a66375689ec7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1.2"; filename="file1.2"
Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PHhtbD4gICAKICAgIDxoZWxsbz5TdGFjazwvaGVsbG8+CjwveG1sPg==
--MIMEBoundary_dfa6d9a4ea9eee573969c1fae03dd6667159a66375689ec7--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `BuilderMediator` can do that, what you would to achieve.
Checkout this: [Builder+Mediator documentation.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Builder+Mediator)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but to get it working i had to made sode trick when i post a message with a body